# Receive data from client without using "dataReceived" function in Twisted

Tags: python, server, twisted, twisted.internet

How to receive the data from the client, bypassing the standard class function Protocol? For example,

```
class TW(protocol.Protocol):
    def get_data(delim = '\n'):
        #some code
        return data
```

I.e, without using the function "dataReceived", and not freezing all other the server clients?

Comment: You have to write asynchronous/non-blocking code in twisted. Show what is in the function so we can make it asynchronous.

Comment: @ESYSCODER, so, I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't bypass `dataReceived` unless you like doing things the hard way :D. You can do what ever you're doing in `get_data()` in `dataReceived()`. Alternatively, you could add a `data` param in your `get_data()` and do a callback form `dataReceived`.

```
class TW(Protocol):
    def get_data(data, delim='\n'):
        # some code
        return result

    def dataReceived(self, data):
        result = self.get_data(data, delim='\r\n')
        # do some more stuff
```